# Capturing reference as value in Lambda expressions

Tags: c++, c++17, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

```
int TestMethod(const std::map<std::string, std::string>& map)
{

  auto m1 = [map=map]()
  {
    // is map here captured as reference or value ?
    std::cout << map.at("test") << std::endl;
    return 1;
  };
  
  return m1();
}
```

Inside `m1`, is `map` captured as value or as reference?
PS this is only a simplistic example, m1 gets called on another thread sometimes throws a

> Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
> 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000010

Compiler is C++17 , clang on a MAC.

Comment: Judging from the [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture), it looks like you are creating a variable named `map` that is initialized by the value `map`. Not sure if that will work. You probably just want `[map]`, not `[map=map]`.

Comment: "*is `map` captured as value or as reference?*" - An easy way to determine that for yourself is to look at the memory address of `map` outside the lambda vs the memory address of `map` inside the lambda. If they differ, then the capture is by value. If they are the same, then the capture is by reference.

Comment: If there is no `&` in the capture, then it's a value. It's a very simple rule (just ignore the behavior of `this`)
.

Answer (score 0):

That's a capture by copy. `[&map=map]` would be a capture by reference.